# How to solve ImportError: cannot import name 'ssl' on Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, openssl, pyenv

I am using [pyenv](https://www.developerfiles.com/installing-multiple-python-versions-in-mac-os-x/) with Python 3.6.0 on a MAC OS Catalina V10.15.5. I have updated openssl with brew to the latest version (**openssl@1.1**):

```
brew install openssl
```

But now I am getting the following errors in my Python virtual environments, for instance when using Boto3:

```
from urllib3.util.ssl_ import ( ImportError: cannot import name 'ssl'
```

How can I link back my [pyenv](https://www.developerfiles.com/installing-multiple-python-versions-in-mac-os-x/) environments to SSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was recently facing the same issue. The solution is forcing the reinstallation of the Python versions you are using within your virtual envs.

For instance for Python 3.6.0:

```
pyenv install -f 3.6.0
```

Output:

```
python-build: use openssl from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Installing Python-3.6.0...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk
Installed Python-3.6.0 to /Users/andrew/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0
```

As you see in the output: **"python-build: use openssl from homebrew"** it will link Python to the current openssl version defined by Homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

```
# ImportError: cannot import name 'SSLv3_METHOD' from 'OpenSSL.SSL'
pip3 install pyopenssl==22.0.0

# AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms'
pip3 install cryptography==38.0.4
```

You need to set a special version of pyopenssl, `SSLv2` and `SSLv3` is no longer supported after 22.1.0. [changelog here](https://pypi.org/project/pyOpenSSL/)

[image]